# Why was the parah aduma found in 2002 disqualified?

Tags: history, animals, invalid-pasul, parah-adumah

In 2002, various news sources [reported](http://www.templeinstitute.org/archive/red_heifer_born.htm) that a red heifer was found and the [Temple Institute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_Institute) in Israel declared it kosher. Many of these sources later reported that the parah aduma was disqualified later that year, but I cannot find any information on why it was disqualified. Does anybody know why the 2002 red heifer was disqualified?

Comment: It could be my computer screen, but that cow looks nothing like red. It looks like just a darker shade of brown, totally expected and common genetic variation.

Comment: @AL Well it was originally accepted, so I guess it was considered to be the right color.

Comment: I wonder on what basis they considered it to be the right color in the first place.

Comment: @AL I don't know. It looks pretty red to me. I don't know *exactly* what color the parah aduma is supposed to be, though.

Comment: http://www.thelakewoodscoop.com/news/2015/01/photos-is-a-local-businessmans-cow-a-parah-adumah.html

Comment: @AL 'red cows' aren't actually red like you imagine it, it is more of a brown color with red strong red tints I believe

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [GlobalNext.org - page 5](http://www.globalnext.org/files/Temple%20Institute%20Interview%20Article.pdf) the Para Aduma born in 2002 was disqualified as it grew 3 white hairs.

Comment: This link seems to have gone dead. Are you able to find another source?

Comment: @Daniel: Sorry I do not have another source. The link was active when the answer was submitted.

Answer (score 4):

Since the link in Gershon Gold's answer no longer works and I have been unsuccessful at finding any other information online, I decided to email the Temple Institute in Jerusalem. This is a quote from the email I received back:

> Previous candidates for parah adumah have been disqualified after having grown more than two non-red hairs. A parah adumah born a year ago in New Jersey was disqualified after it became pregnant and gave birth.

So apparently the 2002 parah adumah did indeed grow more than two non-red hairs.