# How can a parah adumah be validated?

Tags: animals, inspection, parah-adumah

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30407/1713) links to a post from the [Temple Institute](http://www.templeinstitute.org) that mentions that a red heifer was born in Israel in 2002 and that a couple of rabbis had traveled to check the cow and verified that it was indeed kosher to serve as a [parah aduma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_heifer). What properties were the rabbis looking for in their verification, and how rigorous is the vetting process?

Comment: Most likely the proximity of white hairs to each other, or the existence of white hairs according to one opinion.

Comment: http://www.breakingisraelnews.com/17303/holy-cow-red-heifer-born-us/#f4C78IBOyvG8KaIh.97

Comment: @YeZ probably also whatever evidence they can get regarding wither it had ever carried anything, right?

Comment: @IsaacMoses depending on who they were purchasing it from, they might just ask him.  If it carried does not necessarily invalidate it - it had to be לרצון בעלים, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Mishnah Parah 2:5

> היו בה שתי שערות לבנות או שחורות, בתוך גומה אחת, או בתוך שתי כוסות והן מוכיחות זו על זו--פסולה.
>
> If it has 2 white or black hairs within one "depression," or within two "cups" in such a way that they clearly go together, it is invalid.

The Mishna goes on to discuss other details, such as if the roots are red.

Among other details, this would be a primary criterion to check, as the red hair is the defining feature of the red heifer.

Comment: But what is "red"?

Comment: @Daniel It's a color.  If you want to know how they defined red for the purposes of parah aduma, you could [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) that, but I think it's a separate question.